# Circular Progressbar with streaming online url?

Tags: android

I want to make circular progress bar for online streaming URL with update progress, as shown in the image below.

[image]

This is online url streaming code but in this custom progresswheel not updated perfactly with streaming data.

```
 package com.gametech.stream;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StreamingMediaPlayer 
{

        private static final int INTIAL_KB_BUFFER = 96 * 10 / 8;// assume
        // 96kbps*10secs/8bits
        // per byte

        //private static final int INTIAL_KB_BUFFER = 15 * 10 / 8;// assume

        private TextView textStreamed;

        private ImageButton playButton;

        //private ProgressBar progressBar;

        private ProgressWheel stream_progress;

        // Track for display by progressBar
        private long mediaLengthInKb, mediaLengthInSeconds;

        private int totalKbRead = 0;

        // Create Handler to call View updates on the main UI thread.
        private final Handler handler = new Handler();

        private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

        private File downloadingMediaFile;

        private boolean isInterrupted;

        private Context context;

        private int counter = 0;

        /*public StreamingMediaPlayer(Context context, TextView textStreamed,ImageButton playButton, Button streamButton, ProgressBar progressBar)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.textStreamed = textStreamed;
            this.playButton = playButton;
            this.progressBar = progressBar;
        }*/

        /*public StreamingMediaPlayer(Context context, TextView textStreamed,ImageButton playButton, Button streamButton, ProgressBar progressBar)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.textStreamed = textStreamed;
            this.playButton = playButton;
            this.progressBar = progressBar;
        }*/

        public StreamingMediaPlayer(Context context, TextView textStreamed,ImageButton playButton, Button streamButton, ProgressWheel progressBar)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.textStreamed = textStreamed;
            this.playButton = playButton;

            stream_progress = progressBar;
        }

        /**
        * Progressivly download the media to a temporary location and update the
        * MediaPlayer as new content becomes available.
        */
        public void startStreaming(final String mediaUrl, long mediaLengthInKb,long mediaLengthInSeconds) throws IOException
        {

            this.mediaLengthInKb = mediaLengthInKb;
            this.mediaLengthInSeconds = mediaLengthInSeconds;

            Runnable r = new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        downloadAudioIncrement(mediaUrl);
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        Log.e(getClass().getName(),
                                "Unable to initialize the MediaPlayer for fileUrl="
                                + mediaUrl, e);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            };
            new Thread(r).start();
        }

        /**
        * Download the url stream to a temporary location and then call the
        * setDataSource for that local file
        */
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public void downloadAudioIncrement(String mediaUrl) throws IOException
        {

            URLConnection cn = new URL(mediaUrl).openConnection();
            cn.connect();
            InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
            if (stream == null)
            {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(),
                        "Unable to create InputStream for mediaUrl:" + mediaUrl);
            }

            downloadingMediaFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"downloadingMedia.dat");

            // Just in case a prior deletion failed because our code crashed or
            // something, we also delete any previously
            // downloaded file to ensure we start fresh. If you use this code,
            // always delete
            // no longer used downloads else you'll quickly fill up your hard disk
            // memory. Of course, you can also
            // store any previously downloaded file in a separate data cache for
            // instant replay if you wanted as well.
            if (downloadingMediaFile.exists())
            {
                downloadingMediaFile.delete();
            }

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(downloadingMediaFile);
            byte buf[] = new byte[16384];
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            int totalBytesRead = 0, incrementalBytesRead = 0;
            do
            {
                int numread = stream.read(buf);
                if (numread <= 0)
                break;
                out.write(buf, 0, numread);
                totalBytesRead += numread;
                incrementalBytesRead += numread;
                totalKbRead = totalBytesRead / 1000;

                testMediaBuffer();
                fireDataLoadUpdate();
            }
            while (validateNotInterrupted());
            stream.close();
            if (validateNotInterrupted())
            {
                fireDataFullyLoaded();
            }
        }

        private boolean validateNotInterrupted()
        {
            if (isInterrupted)
            {
                if (mediaPlayer != null)
                {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    // mediaPlayer.release();

                    /*Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Ring Completed...");
                    playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_play_new);*/
                }
                return false;
            } 
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        /**
        * Test whether we need to transfer buffered data to the MediaPlayer.
        * Interacting with MediaPlayer on non-main UI thread can causes crashes to
        * so perform this using a Handler.
        */
        private void testMediaBuffer()
        {
            Runnable updater = new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    if (mediaPlayer == null)
                    {
                        // Only create the MediaPlayer once we have the minimum
                        // buffered data
                        if (totalKbRead >= INTIAL_KB_BUFFER)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                startMediaPlayer();
                            } 
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Log.e(getClass().getName(),
                                        "Error copying buffered conent.", e);
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                    else if (mediaPlayer.getDuration() - mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() <= 1000)
                    {
                        // NOTE: The media player has stopped at the end so transfer
                        // any existing buffered data
                        // We test for < 1second of data because the media player
                        // can stop when there is still
                        // a few milliseconds of data left to play
                        transferBufferToMediaPlayer();
                    }
                }
            };
            handler.post(updater);
        }

        private void startMediaPlayer()
        {
            try
            {
                File bufferedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "playingMedia"
                + (counter++) + ".dat");

                // We double buffer the data to avoid potential read/write errors
                // that could happen if the
                // download thread attempted to write at the same time the
                // MediaPlayer was trying to read.
                // For example, we can't guarantee that the MediaPlayer won't open a
                // file for playing and leave it locked while
                // the media is playing. This would permanently deadlock the file
                // download. To avoid such a deadloack,
                // we move the currently loaded data to a temporary buffer file that
                // we start playing while the remaining
                // data downloads.
                moveFile(downloadingMediaFile, bufferedFile);

                Log.e(getClass().getName(),
                "Buffered File path: " + bufferedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                Log.e(getClass().getName(),
                "Buffered File length: " + bufferedFile.length() + "");

                mediaPlayer = createMediaPlayer(bufferedFile);

                // We have pre-loaded enough content and started the MediaPlayer so
                // update the buttons & progress meters.
                mediaPlayer.start();
                startPlayProgressUpdater();
                //playButton.setEnabled(true);
                playButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_pause);
                //playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_pause);
            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error initializing the MediaPlayer.",
                        e);
                return;
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        private MediaPlayer createMediaPlayer(File mediaFile) throws IOException
        {
            MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener()
            {
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra)
                {
                    Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error in MediaPlayer: (" + what
                            + ") with extra (" + extra + ")");
                    return false;
                }
            });

            // It appears that for security/permission reasons, it is better to pass
            // a FileDescriptor rather than a direct path to the File.
            // Also I have seen errors such as "PVMFErrNotSupported" and
            // "Prepare failed.: status=0x1" if a file path String is passed to
            // setDataSource(). So unless otherwise noted, we use a FileDescriptor
            // here.
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mediaFile);
            mPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
            mPlayer.prepare();
            return mPlayer;
        }

        /**
        * Transfer buffered data to the MediaPlayer. NOTE: Interacting with a
        * MediaPlayer on a non-main UI thread can cause thread-lock and crashes so
        * this method should always be called using a Handler.
        */
        private void transferBufferToMediaPlayer()
        {
            try
            {
                // First determine if we need to restart the player after
                // transferring data...e.g. perhaps the user pressed pause
                boolean wasPlaying = mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
                int curPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

                // Copy the currently downloaded content to a new buffered File.
                // Store the old File for deleting later.
                File oldBufferedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),
                "playingMedia" + counter + ".dat");
                File bufferedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "playingMedia"
                + (counter++) + ".dat");

                // This may be the last buffered File so ask that it be delete on
                // exit. If it's already deleted, then this won't mean anything. If
                // you want to
                // keep and track fully downloaded files for later use, write
                // caching code and please send me a copy.
                bufferedFile.deleteOnExit();
                moveFile(downloadingMediaFile, bufferedFile);

                // Pause the current player now as we are about to create and start
                // a new one. So far (Android v1.5),
                // this always happens so quickly that the user never realized we've
                // stopped the player and started a new one
                mediaPlayer.pause();

                // Create a new MediaPlayer rather than try to re-prepare the prior
                // one.
                mediaPlayer = createMediaPlayer(bufferedFile);
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(curPosition);

                // Restart if at end of prior buffered content or mediaPlayer was
                // previously playing.
                // NOTE: We test for < 1second of data because the media player can
                // stop when there is still
                // a few milliseconds of data left to play
                boolean atEndOfFile = mediaPlayer.getDuration() - mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() <= 1000;
                if (wasPlaying || atEndOfFile)
                {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }

                // Lastly delete the previously playing buffered File as it's no
                // longer needed.
                oldBufferedFile.delete();

            } 
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(),
                "Error updating to newly loaded content.", e);
            }
        }

        private void fireDataLoadUpdate()
        {
            Runnable updater = new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    textStreamed.setText((totalKbRead + " Kb"));
                    float loadProgress = ((float) totalKbRead / (float) mediaLengthInKb);

                    stream_progress.setProgress((int) (loadProgress * 100));
                    Log.e("Progress Update::", Math.round(((float) loadProgress / 360) * 100) + "%");
                    //progressBar.setSecondaryProgress((int) (loadProgress * 100));

                    //Log.e(getClass().getName(), String.valueOf(progressBar.getProgress()));
                }
                };
                handler.post(updater);
            }

            private void fireDataFullyLoaded()
            {
                Runnable updater = new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        transferBufferToMediaPlayer();

                        // Delete the downloaded File as it's now been transferred to
                        // the currently playing buffer file.
                        downloadingMediaFile.delete();
                        textStreamed.setText(("Audio Loaded: " + totalKbRead + " Kb"));

                        /*if(mediaPlayer.getDuration() >= mediaLengthInSeconds)
                        {
                            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Ring Completed...");
                            //playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_play_new);
                        }*/
                    }
                };
                handler.post(updater);
        }

        public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer()
        {
            return mediaPlayer;
        }

        public void startPlayProgressUpdater()
        {
            float progress = (((float) mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000) / mediaLengthInSeconds);
            //stream_progress.setProgress((int) (progress * 200));
            //progressBar.setProgress((int) (progress * 100));
            //Log.e(getClass().getName(), String.valueOf(progress * 100));

            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                Runnable notification = new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        startPlayProgressUpdater();
                    }
                };
                handler.postDelayed(notification, 1000);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Ring Completed...");
                playButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
                //playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
                //PlayDialogActivity.img_streamAniumation.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                //CustomizeDialog.img_streamAniumation.setImageResource(R.drawable.anim_white);
            }

            /*if(progress >= mediaLengthInSeconds)
            {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Ring Completed...");
                //playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_play_new);

            }*/
        }

        public void interrupt()
        {
            //playButton.setEnabled(false);
            playButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
            //playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
            isInterrupted = true;
            validateNotInterrupted();
        }

        /**
        * Move the file in oldLocation to newLocation.
        */
        public void moveFile(File oldLocation, File newLocation) throws IOException
        {

            if (oldLocation.exists())
            {
                BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(oldLocation));
                BufferedOutputStream writer = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(newLocation, false));
                try
                {
                    // byte[] buff = new byte[8192];
                    /* changing the size of the buffer */

                    byte[] buff = new byte[16384];

                    int numChars;
                    while ((numChars = reader.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) != -1)
                    {
                        writer.write(buff, 0, numChars);
                    }
                } 
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    throw new IOException("IOException when transferring "
                            + oldLocation.getPath() + " to "
                            + newLocation.getPath());
                } 
                finally
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (reader != null)
                        {
                            writer.close();
                            reader.close();
                        }
                    } 
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        Log.e(getClass().getName(),
                                "Error closing files when transferring "
                                + oldLocation.getPath() + " to "
                                + newLocation.getPath());
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new IOException(
                        "Old location does not exist when transferring "
                        + oldLocation.getPath() + " to "
                        + newLocation.getPath());
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: then make it,best wishes!!

Comment: Fair enough, so what's your question?

Comment: @ravi why dont you post your progress so far, and where are you facing problem

Answer (score 1):

here is the link might be helpful to u : [custom circular progress bar](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel)

Answer (score 0):

You can make this type of circular ProgressBar but in updating the progress depends on several parameters.

if 1) you have used live streaming than the progress time is dependent on the streamer how long he streams in that case showing progress is not possible.

2) if you are streaming the stored file from server than you can measure the length of file & depending on that you'll be able to set the progress per bytes received.

Question How to make this type of ProgressBar ? 
Ans : Can share idea to make it done but not easy as it seems

It is entirely possible to create this and be pixel perfect and without using a series of images .
The problem though is it is a little hard to explain and it is all about layers and rectangles - seriously.

-Layer 1, background, image of the Dark blue circle for showing progress

-Layer 2, rectangle same height and 50% of layer 1 that covers the left hand side of the image, change the anchorpoint to 1, 0.5, image is the uncovers shaded white empty view

-Layer 3, rectangle same height and 50% of layer 1 that covers the right hand side of the image, change the anchorpoint to 0, 0.5, image is the uncovers shaded white empty view

Initially ;

Layer 1 = visible, never moves

Layer 2 = visible, never moves

Layer 3 = visible, moves

The process;

-Rotate Layer 3 from 0 to 360 degrees representing 0 to 100 percent.

-At 180 degress set Layer 2 = hidden, layer 4 = visible

The logic;
The layers act as masks that cover the image as it rotates, when the percentage gets to 50% you swap which masks are shown to manage the correct reveal.

Using this technique you can have very smooth rotations and very precise positions, but it may take some time to understand the logic.

Comment: That's WAY too complicated.  All you need to do is to extend the `View` class and in in the `onPaint` method draw two congruent circles and shade some area on a canvas.

Comment: even your idea is not simple as it seems..that will be better for questioner to understand better if you elaborate it deeply.